# cloudinary upload getting error

Tags: python-3.x, upload, cloudinary

> cloudinary.uploader.upload("Mokhtar_Rahimi.jpg",api_key=API_KEY,api_secret=API_SECRET)

throwing **cloudinary.api.Error**: ('Error parsing server response (%d) - %s. Got - %s', 404, , ValueError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',))

Answer (score 0):

The API_Key and API_Secret should not be set within the upload method but rather in a configuration object or a yml file (see [doc](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_additional_topics#configuration_options)). The upload method should include a required `file` parameters and upload options (see [doc](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload)).